# Blender won't save images

Tags: blender

This should be a simple question. I am unable to save any images I render in blender.

I set the output to be `/home/john/Pictures/binary.png`, the image type to PNG, and checked the "File Extensions" box.

Then when I press f12 (Or Render > Render Image), there is nothing new in my pictures folder.

I've tried running blender using graphical root (gksu), and it still wont let me save anything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to manually save renders.

- First you start with a scene you want to render.
  [image: Example]
- After setting up your image settings, hit <kbd>f12</kbd> to Render.
- Now you will get a rendered image in your viewport (under the UV/Image editor).
  [image: Rendered image]
- However, this image is not saved automatically.
- To save it, you need to click on the image menu:
  [image: Image menu button]
- And you will get the option to save the image:
  [image: Menu]
  [image: Saving thingy]

Answer (score 0):

Once your F12 render is completed, you must save the image. To do that, you can hit F3 on your keyboard enter the name and brows to the path, and hit "save as image". Renders only automatically get saved in the output file if you are rendering an animation.

Answer (score -1):

try save the image as copy :) ( Save as Copy )
friendly
Anteas